# Access to a slot function inside a child component in VusJS

Tags: vue.js, tiptap

I'm trying to use [tiptap](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap). Actually it works, but what I'm trying to do is to access the "isActive" slot from outside the `editor` component, and I don't know how to do it.

Here is a codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/v07xnxo807?file=/src/App.vue

You see the Editor component is called from the App.vue. The buttons in the Editor component are activated depending on the "isActive" slot functions.
What I would like is to access this slot to get for example the value of `isActive.bold()` from the App.vue, in order to update the model of a "multiple button" you can find on Vuetify: https://vuetifyjs.com/fr-FR/components/button-groups/

Here is for example what I could have:

```html
<editor-menu-bar :editor="editor" v-slot="{ commands, isActive }">
  <v-btn-toggle
    v-model="toggle_multiple"
    dense
    background-color="primary"
    dark
    multiple
    class="my-2"
  >
    <v-btn :color="isActive.bold()?'red':'green'" @click="commands.bold">
      <v-icon>mdi-format-bold</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="commands.italic">
      <v-icon>mdi-format-italic</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="commands.strike">
      <v-icon>mdi-format-strikethrough</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="commands.underline">
      <v-icon>mdi-format-underline</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="commands.blockquote">
      <v-icon>mdi-format-quote-open</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-btn-toggle>
</editor-menu-bar>
```

And the toggle_multiple would be computed depending on the different "isActive" function values.

I already tried:

```js
computed: {
  toggle_multiple: function () {
    let t = []
    if (editor)  {console.log("Bold: "+editor.isActive.bold())}
    return t
  }
},
```

But I receive this error: `error  'editor' is not defined`

I'm open to any suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property `isActive` is stored in the tiptap instance (in your case it's `this.editor`):

In HTML:

```html
<div>{{editor.isActive.bold()}}</div>
```

In JS:

```html
<div>{{toggle_multiple}}</div>
```

```js
computed: {
  toggle_multiple () {
    // Keep in mind, other properties like ".isActive.heading()" will be undefined
    // until you import the extension for it.
    // So the function "heading" below exists only if you're using that extension
    // console.log(this.editor.isActive.heading({ level: 2 })
    return this.editor.isActive.bold()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer. I had to put a condition because before it's mounted, my `editor` was `null`, so I couldn't get the computed property to work correctly... Thank you for your explanations.